# O que é o NPM e o Node?

Tags: node.js, aplicação-web, npm

O título da pergunta já diz tudo.
Há muitos artigos sobre isso, mas de uma forma clara e para iniciante, o que é de facto o NPM e o que faz? Tal como o Node?

O que é que contribuem na construção de sites?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## NodeJs

[NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) é um *runtime* que permite a execução de código JavaScript fora dos navegadores. Pode ser usado dentro de outras aplicações ou mesmo sozinho. Ele é um ambiente que funciona como uma máquina virtual para a execução do *scripts* JS.

Se conhece o PHP pense que ele é tanto a linguagem quanto o seu ambiente de execução. É um contraponto ao C# que é a linguagem e o .NET é o ambiente de execução. O NodeJs é apenas o ambiente. A linguagem dele é o JavaScript. Então pense que o NodeJs em si é todo o pacote do ambiente.

Fazendo uma outra comparação é o JRE, ou seja, aquele pacote do Java que você é obrigado instalar no seu computador por causa de algum software que precisa e foi feito em Java (acessar sites de bancos, por exemplo).

## Aplicações web

É muito usado no lado do servidor para atender as demandas de aplicações web. Há algumas vantagens nele, também há desvantagens. Mas em geral é só uma opção. Alguns optam porque tem alguma necessidade, outros adotam porque JavaScript é a única linguagem que conhece e não quer usar outra que pode ser mais adequado no lado do servidor. Em geral ele é executado sem servidor. Algo que hoje é comum em outras tecnologias, mas ele tem o mérito de demonstrar que isso não só é viável, mas também desejável em várias situações.

## Vantagens

Uma das vantagens é um **bom mecanismo de eventos e execução assíncrona não bloqueante**. Então é conhecido por dar grande escalabilidade. Algo que outras tecnologias o podem também.

Seu sucesso se deve, além de permitir JS que as pessoas já estavam acostumadas, ao fato que as tecnologias geralmente tinham dificuldade para lidar com operações paralelas e o sequencial não atendia bem. Especialmente PHP que é muito usado no lado do servidor não é bom nisso. As pessoas viram ele como salvação.

Ele não escala bem para vários processadores (núcleos), pelo menos não acontecia, não sei como está hoje.

Ele possui uma API mais extensa do que o JS possui em um navegador, pode acessar banco de dados e arquivos, por exemplo. E é claro que se não roda no navegador não faz sentido ter as APIs específicas para ele.

Atualmente ele usa o mecanismo de JS V8 criado pela Google para o Chrome que era o mais rápido na época que o NodeJs foi criado, mas o mais rápido é uma característica transitória. Até onde eu sei nada impede que um dia possa ser trocado, ainda que duvide que aconteça, a não ser por algum motivo grave, haveria problemas de compatibilidade.

> O que é que contribuem na construção de sites?

Se pensar em sites como o lado do cliente NodeJs não contribui em nada. Por acaso ele pode ser usado na parte do servidor, mas não é diferente de usar outro ambiente/linguagem.

## NPM

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) (Node Package Manager) é só um pacote de gerenciamento de módulos de códigos JS para instalar junto ao NodeJs e poder usar nas suas aplicações, ou até mesmo suas aplicações que precisam ser incluídas junto ao Node.

A grosso modo é um instalador cuidando das dependências evitando ter que mantê-las junto da sua aplicação e cuidar das atualizações. O que [nem sempre funciona como o esperado](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/03/npm-infection). Além disso é um repositório de módulos.

## Deno

Agora existe o [Deno](https://deno.land/) que é melhor que o Node.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente resposta, mas eu complementaria dizendo que o NPM ainda é utilizado para gerenciar pacotes, dentro de um ambiente de desenvolvimento por exemplo ele controla as dependências, dentro do package json são informados as dependências que ele deve instalar no projeto. Evitando dessa forma, o commit de componentes externos ao seu projeto para o seu repositório git exemplificando.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold dei uma melhorada nisso

Comment: muito obrigado.

Answer (score 13):

### **Node**

`Node.js` é uma plataforma construída sobre o motor `JavaScript` do Google Chrome para facilmente construir aplicações de rede rápidas e escaláveis. `Node.js` usa um modelo de I/O direcionada a evento não bloqueante que o torna leve e eficiente, ideal para aplicações em tempo real com troca intensa de dados através de dispositivos distribuídos. Seu objetivo é ajudar programadores na criação de aplicações de alta escalabilidade (como um servidor web), com códigos capazes de manipular dezenas de milhares de conexões simultâneas, numa única máquina física.

**Como funciona?**

O Node roda em uma `JavaScript` V8 VM. `JavaScript` no lado do servidor pode ser um conceito novo para todos que trabalharam exclusivamente com o JavaScript no lado do cliente. O motor JavaScript V8 é o motor que a Google usa com seu navegador Chrome. Poucas pessoas pensam sobre o que realmente acontece com o `JavaScript` no lado do cliente. A engine `JavaScript` realmente interpreta o código e o executa. Com o V8 a Google criou um ultrarrápido interpretador escrito em `C++`, com um outro aspecto único: você pode baixar a engine e incorporá-la em qualquer aplicação desejada. Isso não está restrito em rodar em um navegador. Então Node atualmente usa o motor `JavaScript` V8 escrito pela Google e propõe que seja usado no servidor.

### **NPM**

NPM é o nome reduzido de *Node Package Manager* (Gerenciador de Pacotes do Node). A NPM é duas coisas: Primeiro, e mais importante, é um repositório online para publicação de projetos de código aberto para o `Node.js`; segundo, ele é um utilitário de linha de comando que interage com este repositório online, que ajuda na instalação de pacotes, gerenciamento de versão e gerenciamento de dependências..

A partir da versão `Node.js` 0.5.x que o NPM passou a ser integrado ao instalador do `Node.js` e isso simplificou a vida dos desenvolvedores, pois antes disso existia diversos gerenciadores de pacotes para o `Node.js`.

Ele também mantém um repositório online NPM que também é mantido pela Joyent, atualmente ele contém mais de 30 mil módulos *open-source*.

**O que faz?**

Quando você vai desenvolver uma aplicação  e decide usar uma biblioteca, por exemplo, a biblioteca assíncrona de Coalan McMahon, você só precisa usar o comando `npm install async`, e o módulo específico será instalado no diretório atual dentro da pasta `./node_modules/`. Uma vez instalada sua pasta `node_modules`, você será capaz de usar [`require()`](http://nodebr.com/como-funciona-a-funcao-require-do-node-js/) nela como se fossem módulos internos do seu projeto.

Referência: [NodeBR](http://nodebr.com/)