# Por que o .NET Core foi criado?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Eu já sei o que é e como usar, mas queria entender o objetivo da Microsoft para sua criação. Eu sei que tinha problemas no .NET Framework, mas não entendi bem porque decidiram criar este novo produto. O que eles ganham com isso?

Qual o futuro dele? Posso confiar que a Microsoft não vai estragar tudo?

Já vi [O que é o .Net Core?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).

Comment: No link que postou há um Q&A informado pelo @bigown que provavelmente irá responder suas perguntas: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dorischen/2014/11/12/microsoft-takes-net-open-source-and-cross-platform/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

De fato, o .NET Framework é uma plataforma interessante que tem seu mérito, mas não serve para tudo. Acredito eu que o advento dos *containers*, microsserviços, IoT, internet *always on* e a ascensão do mobile fizeram a Microsoft rever a estratégia e perceberam que o .NET não atendia os novos requisitos.

Na verdade, dois produtos foram criados para atender as novas demandas, o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) e o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). O primeiro torna os executáveis totalmente independentes, como se tivesse escrito em C/C++, por exemplo, claro que existem algumas limitações do que o .NET pode fazer, mas poucas. O segundo precisa de um *runtime*, mas não precisa ser uma plataforma completa como é o .NET "full", é muito mais enxuto.

Muita coisa mudou desde o texto original escrito aqui então leia também [O .NET Framework está morto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Com isso fica mais fácil funcionar nesses modelos novos citados acima. <strike>O .NET Framework ainda é o mais adequado para desenvolvimento desktop</strike>. Mas quase sempre, o .NET Core é mais adequado para rodar em pequenos dispositivos com diversos propósitos, servidores, não importando o modelo, e algumas aplicações que rodam em desktop, mas que não são típicas. O desenvolvimento de jogos pode se beneficiar também.

Claro que a Microsoft não domina as plataformas desses ambientes novos (ela até está tentando em alguns novos). Muito da utilidade do .NET fora do desktop é em plataformas onde ela não atua e um novo .NET que funcionasse bem nelas era necessário, não poderia ter as vinculações com Windows existentes no .NET original.

Um ponto que eu acho bem interessante é a concorrência do [Node.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157034/101) (na verdade o que fez ele ter essa fama foi a [libuv](http://libuv.org/)). Ele possui um servidor baseado em eventos que é muito melhor que aplicações web tradicionais (já tem versões mais novas todo novo que é muito melhor, não a toa que se dá tão bem em *benchmarks* como o [TechEmpower](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r19&hw=ph&test=plaintext)). O modelo antigo do .NET não favorece isso, o .NET/ASP.NET Core está mais preparado para atender esta demanda, e [deixa o Node.js comer poeira em performance (e obviamente o .NET antigo)](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks). Hoje web se dá muito por troca intensiva de pequenas mensagens, o modelo anterior não funcionava bem mais.

[image: Resultado do Techempower]

Claro que só isto não foi suficiente. Eles compraram a Xamarin para atender o mobile e acho que a tendência é o .NET Core ir sendo incorporado nele cada vez mais. [Hoje tem o MAUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455179/101).

Também perceberam que abrir o código e o projeto não era só atender as expectativas dos desenvolvedores, mas também fundamental para conseguir alcançar rapidamente melhorias que só uma comunidade pode dar. [Está lá no GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core), todo mundo pode participar.

Claro que o .NET estava um pouco *bloated* também, foi a oportunidade para dar um jeito nisso.

Ela não parou por aí. Também começou fornecer outras ferramentas para ajudar o desenvolvimento em outras plataformas, como o [Visual Studio Code](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152242/101), [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) e até o [SQL Server for Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para complementar a *stack*.

O projeto do .NET Core é amplamente financiado pela Microsoft, mas é de propriedade da [.NET Foundation](https://dotnetfoundation.org/) e o projeto é muito aberto, não é algo que só a Microsoft manda. Claro que ela tem peso, como ocorre em todo projeto aberto, a não ser os fracassados. Mas é impressionante a quantidade de *commits* de terceiros que o projeto está recebendo. O projeto será o que a comunidade quer, na medida que ela seja coerente. E a licença é MIT que é a verdadeira licença que dá liberdade.

Muitas funcionalidades desenvolvidas no .NET Core estão sendo transpostas para o .NET Framework, mas não todas, algumas por não fazer sentido, outras porque não há tanto interesse ali. A impressão que dá é que o .NET *full* entrou em estado de produto terminado e continuará recebendo pequenas melhorias, longe de ser um produto abandonado, mas a atenção é no .NET Core. Agora é suportado, mas não evoluído mais.

E ele vem melhorando muito a compatibilidade com o .NET Framework:

[image: APIs do .NET Core]

Partindo do 3.0 tem "tudo" o que precisa para substituir o .NET Framework por completo. E no .NET 5 que perde o nome Core, está ainda melhor. O que não tem é porque não faz mais sentido ou era ruim e é melhor não usar mais.

Para organizar todas essas implementações existe o [.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na versões acima. Que agora não faz muito sentido mais.

Em resumo, a Microsoft está sendo oposta a tudo o que as pessoas que a odeiam acham que ela sempre faz. Claro que atende seus interesses, mas isso é normal, ocorre com todo mundo que não vive de poesia :) Ela fez porque havia essa demanda no mercado, por isso o mercado competitivo é sempre bom.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É por causa disso que eu queria poder favoritar respostas.

Comment: Favorita a pergunta como eu faço :) aí todas respostas que eu positivei eu sei que são boas na página