# É possível criar um aplicação inteiramente com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web, back-end

Sou novo na área de desenvolvimento (aliás, nem estou na área ainda). Eu gostaria de saber se é possível integrar *back e front-end* **inteiramente** por JavaScript **puro**. Pois eu acredito que se eu puder me garantir no JavaScript puro, eu posso aprender qualquer *framework* de JavaScript com facilidade e segurança.

Dá para construir uma aplicação somente com JavaScript para poder ter meu primeiro trabalho no portfólio?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Node.js serve para isso, mas há também outras implementações de javascript que podem ser usadas, sugiro que faça uma pergunta mais específica nesse caso. Quanto ao resto da sua pergunta, acho que é algo que não fica muito longe disso daqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5487/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa se o motivo pra fechar é este exemplo *linkado*, então definitivamente eu discordo do fechamento. Mas a pergunta realmente não está muito boa.

Comment: Se você estiver pensando em *Javascript* apenas como linguagem, sim é possível, pois como foi mencionado pelo @VictorStafusa, Node.js usa linguagem *Javascript* e roda no servidor, mas bem diferentes no que diz respeito à funcionalidade (os objetos do lado cliente e servidor são completamente diferentes, só a linguagem é a mesma)

Comment: Você já deve ter ouvido este ditado, mas aí vai: "quando tudo o que tenho na mão é um martelo, qualquer coisa parece ser um prego". Por que limitar-se a uma só ferramenta, se existe uma gama variada, para cada tipo de problema?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos que você terá assim que aceitar a resposta).

Answer (score 6):

Sim, é possível já que existe o [Node.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157034/101) ([Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/444449/101) também) para rodar no *backend*. Claro que há algumas diferenças na API do *browser* e do servidor, e isso é mais importante que a linguagem em si.

Se você gostar e se dá muito bem com JS pode ser uma boa, tem facilidades em usar uma linguagem só. Mas muitas vezes a solução pode não ser a mais adequada.

Particularmente eu estou indo em direção contrária, já que há fortes críticas ao JavaScript. Uma delas é a proliferação de *framewoks* e ferramentas.

Eu prefiro usar C# em *backend* e agora vou usá-lo também no *frontend* através do [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101).

Diversas linguagens estão fazendo o mesmo através do [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101). Por mim o JS não tem futuro, mas pra muita gente tem.

Minha visão foge um pouco da maré corrente. E muitas pessoas bastante fortes na área pensam o mesmo. O que importa é saber o fundamento. Essa coisa de escolher uma linguagem e aprender programar assim, resolve em parte o problema, tem muita gente que se dá bem dessa forma, mas é difícil se tornar um excelente profissional assim. Conheço muita gente que até se torna conhecido, tem bons empregos, até porque são capazes de se comunicar bem e conseguem se vender bem só com isso. Mas é diferente de dominar a programação, de ser capaz de resolver qualquer problema, de ser criativo.

> It is practically impossible to teach good programming to students that have had a prior exposure to BASIC: as potential programmers they are mentally mutilated beyond hope of regeneration
>
> -- Edsger W. Dijkstra

Eu diria que isto vale hoje para JS (não só, mas a lista é grande). Embora quase todo mundo que eu conheço que se tornou profissional da área e começou com BASIC alcançou algum grau de excelência. De fato JS cria vícios e falta de entendimento bem piores que o BASIC fazia nas pobres mentes.

Note que entende estar entrando na área e já ter um portfólio, antes de saber o que fazer. É, parece que é assim agora, depois o pessoa vai reclamar que a área paga mal. Por isso que no passado ninguém contratava gente mais velha, hoje preferem essas, são as pessoas que aprenderam.

Espero ter podido dar um bom direcionamento, foi minha intenção, apesar da criticidade da mensagem, até porque hoje em dia falta isso também para as pessoas tomarem decisões mais equilibradas e fundamentadas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre.
Para o desenvolvimento de aplicações utilizando puramente JS existem inúmeros frameworks para isso.

Para back-end existe o NODEJS

Front aconselho reactjs (Este framework vem crescendo muito no mercado)

para mobile tbm existe o react-native que é bem semelhante ao JS.

E caso queira rodar uma aplicação desktop de fato, existe o electronJS que faz o mesmo (utilizando webview)

Answer (score 0):

Hoje em dia é possível, o JavaScript embora seja uma linguagem front-end, ela permite construir aplicações backend, há alguns frameworks que fazem uso dela como backend como node.js. Ela também é conhecida com ECMAScript, e vem evoluindo muito nos últimos anos, da versão 6 para a versão 7 e por aí vai...

A Microsoft criou o Javascript em 96 e a Netscape melhorou, normalizando a linguagem, passando a adotar as métricas de ECMAScript, nasceu para renderizar conteúdos HTML, basicamente a estrutura de renderização de uma página é baseada em JavaScript através da manipulação do [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM).

Os navegadores são renderizadores de HTML, tudo que é feito hoje em relação a HTML, passar por esse processo de construção e/ou reconstrução, os eventos, os elementos, tudo é que será apresentado como estrutura de elementos HTML, é através do DOM, dentre diversas outras coisas que são lidas, e interpretadas, antes da mágica acontecer, é definida regras síncrona ou assíncrona, dependendo da hierarquia estabelecida em seus eventos e funções.

Cada navegador tem um motor de renderização, a maioria hoje reconhece o javascript e permite que ele seja utilizado, isso se o usuário não desativá-lo manualmente, a partir daí você tem acesso as funções nativas, e pode enxergar isso através do console do seu navegador, basta escrever `window` e dar enter e terá o console.log da primeira camada de suas funções nativas.

Dentro de um código javascript, vc pode colocar o método nativo console.log(objeto) para ver no seu console saídas de impressão dos elementos trabalhados, que podem ser diversos, como objetos, strings, números, booleanos etc.

Mas para tirar o melhor proveito disso, se você não deseja ter familiaridade com o node.js ou acha muito complicado, você pode optar pelo uso de qualquer outra linguagem backend (lado servidor) que suporte construção de estruturas de dados em modelo [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-pt.html), que é basicamente uma estrutura de dados similar ao XML, cujo os dados são consumidos pelos métodos do javascript. Ainda que não precise utilizar estruturas backend, pode apenas consumir um arquivo do tipo: `/path/arquivo.json`, como se estivesse acessando um banco de dados, só que é apenas um arquivo de apresentação de dados.

Ainda para aplicações de APP, como mobile, você tem o react-native, que usa Javascript para conversar com arquiteturas nativas de forma híbrida (tanto Android como IOs). Você pode querer se informar a respeito do [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) que hoje é o mais novo e está competindo com o react-native, foi desenvolvido pelo Google e utiliza sua própria linguagem Dart.

Para desktop, você pode usar modelos de estruturas em javascript muito similares, utilizando apenas o react.

Outros exemplos de frameworks / libs voltados para Javascript:

- Angular 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 +
- AngularJS
- React
- jQuery (biblioteca)

Comment: Eu não entendo o porque negativar essa resposta. Embora eu pertença a uma escola de pensamento que encare o Javascript como uma linguagem de multipropósito existe uma escola de pensamente que encara o Javascript como uma linguagem de domínio específico e principal argumento deles é que o NodeJs é uma implementação do Google V8 que é engine de muitos navegadores.