# O que é e como usar o Sass e o Npm em Bootstrap 4?

Tags: npm, sass, bootstrap-4

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o bootstrap e surgiu estas palavras e gostaria de entender o que elas são e como se usa.

Answer (score 1):

Sass (Syntactically Awesome StyleSheets) - É uma extensão do CSS. Um pré-processador CSS. Na verdade é basicamente uma "linguagem" que é transliterada em CSS. Voce poderá ler em detalhes aqui: [Sass - reference](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

A vantagem do uso do SASS é que ela adiciona elementos de programação que não existem no CSS, como o uso de variáveis e Procedures (chamadas de MIXINS). Com isso o SASS organiza o CSS de uma forma procedural.

NPM (Node Package Manager) - É um utilitário de distribuição de packages. Similiar ao NuGet (.NET) e ao Mavem (Java). 
Veja uma melhor descriçao aqui: [O que é o NPM e o Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157034/o-que-%C3%A9-o-npm-e-o-node)

O NPM hoje é o utilitario mais usado (hoje em 2018) para distribuição e manuntenção de pacotes em desenvolvimento WEB.

Agora como isso é relacionado ao Bootstrap4?

O Bootstrap é um framework CSS. Nas versões anteriores era usado o LESS (equivalente ao SASS) como pré-processador CSS. O SASS é menos complexo que o LESS (veja uma referencia aqui: [SASS vs LESS](https://learn.onemonth.com/sass-vs-less/)) então foi optado como padrão.

Uma das formas de integrar o Bootstrap4 no seu projeto é usar o NPM. Isso simplifica bastante o processo de desenvolvimento.

Se você quiser saber mais sobre as novidades do Bootstrap 4 eu recomendo esse artigo: [Bootstrap: As mudanças da v4](http://coral.ufsm.br/pet-si/index.php/bootstrap-as-mudancas-da-v4/)

Comment: @MarceloBoni Obrigado pelas correções. Meu teclado é francês Canadá. Não tenho ~. Para acentuar eu tenho que usar as conbinações ALT+198 =ã  e Alt+228=õ, o que às vezes passa batido.